# SingleStore exception no_data_found

Tags: oracle, memsql, singlestore

I’m having difficulty finding the exception `no_data_found` in **singlestore**.

In **Oracle**, we use `no_data_found` exception.
Is there any alternative solution in **singlestore** for the `no_data_found` exception?

Comment: Are you trying to raise the no_data_found from a stored procedure or are you doing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is inside a stored procedure, you can use `ER_INTO_VARIABLES_NO_ROWS`. Example is below:

```
create table test(id int primary key, descr varchar(10));
insert into test values (1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three');

delimiter $$
create or replace procedure test_sp(inp_id int)
returns void as
declare
      v_descr varchar(10);
begin
       begin
         select descr into v_descr from test where id = inp_id;      
         echo select v_descr;
         exception
           when ER_INTO_VARIABLES_NO_ROWS then 
                echo select 'No rows found';
        end;
end $$
delimiter ;

call test_sp(1); -- returns 'one'
call test_sp(100); -- returns 'No rows found'
```